# Business object with context or not?

Tags: c#, business-logic

Which one is more preferred way to implement business object (and why)?

Without separate "context"

```
class Product
{
   public string Code { get; set; }

   public void Save()
   {
       using (IDataService service = IoC.GetInstance<IDataService>())
       {
           service.Save(this);
       }
   }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.Code = "A1";
p.Save();
```

With separate "context"

```
class Product
{
    private IContext context;

    public Product(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.context.Save(this);
    }
 }
```

And usage would be:

```
using (IContext context = IoC.GetInstance<IContext>())
{
    Product p = new Product(context);
    p.Code = "A1";
    p.Save();
}
```

This all is happening at BL layer (except usage examples), nothing to do with database etc. IDataService is interface to data layer to save business object "somewhere". IContext basically wraps IDataService somehow. Actual business objects are more complex with more properties and references to each other (like Order -> OrderRow <- Product).

My opinion is that first approach is (too) simple and second choice gives more control outside single business object instance....? Is there any guidelines for something like this?

Answer (score 3):

I personally opt for a third version where the object itself does not know how to save itself, but instead relies on another component to save it. This becomes interesting when there are multiple ways to save an object, say saving it to a database, a json stream, an xml stream. Such objects are usually referred to as Serializers.

So in your case, I would go for as simple as this:

```
class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

a serialize for IContext serialization would be:

```
class ContextSerializer
{
    public void SaveProduct(Product prod)
    {
        using(IContext context = IoC.GetInstance<IContext>())
        {
           context.Save(prod);
        }
     }
}
```

usage would be:

```
public void SaveNewProduct(string code)
{
   var prod = new Product() { Code = code };
   var contextSerializer = new ContextSerialzer();
   contextSerializer.SaveProduct(prod);
}
```

This prevents the object from holding on to the context (the field in your example) and keeps your business objects simple. It also seperates concerns.

If you get into the situation where you have inheritance in your business objects, consider the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: If I want to use Lazy loading with related business objects (Like Product has list of Parts), this is not an option I guess? No I have lazy loading implemented relying to context field ....

Comment: I also flagged up this because I have also plans to persist objects in various ways and this seems to be very good choice, but this lazy loading ....

Comment: I don't know of a generic approach for lazy loading, it really does depend on your use case.

Comment: By now I have to stick with implementation where business object holds its context object so it can also pass that context for lazy loader objects (so lazy loading works now). Lifetime of context is managed outside of business object (using block). I have been thinking that other "persisting" methods are used as serializers (like XmlSerializer) and those serializers has nothing to do with lazy loading or context. So in my implementation there is one context which handles IO to data layer and if I want to save business object to somewhere else I use some kind of serializer approach.